# Is there a reliable system restore tool for Linux (Mint)?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, system-restore

Yesterday I plugged my linux working laptop to the docking station and decided to crash completely.

Without going into the details of the damage and the whole recovery process -- which did not take place because it was impossible, I had to completely re-install my system.

Quite a lot of otherwise productive time was spent on (1) looking for a solution -- which did not exist and (2) complete system re-installation and setup to the latest working state.

Affected by this inconvenience I would fancy having a command-line tool where I could specify the system to revert to the latest working snapshot, given that the system takes snapshot regularly. That would save me ~5 hours!

Is there such a system for Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Such a tool does exist, it's called [Timeshift](http://www.howtogeek.com/206491/how-to-restore-your-ubuntu-linux-system-to-its-previous-state/). The linked article is about Ubuntu but it works for multiple distros.

> Wouldn’t it be nice to be able to try a new version of Ubuntu while knowing you can return to the previous version if you don’t like it? We’ll show you a tool that allows you to take a snapshot of your system at any time.
>
> TimeShift is a free tool that is similar to the System Restore feature in Windows. It allows you to initially take a snapshot of your system and then to take incremental snapshots at regular intervals. TimeShift protects only system files and settings, not user files such as documents, pictures, and music. You can use a tool like Back In Time to backup your user files.